# Publishing ASP.Net Core app to Azure silently fails in command line

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to publish a dotnet core app to Azure. I've created a publish profile and using visual studio it all works fine. But since I'd like to setup continuous deployment I need to run the deployment using command line.

The [official documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/web-publishing-vs.html) was pretty helpful in identifying that the `[ProfileName].ps1` is the best plan of attack.

However it gives no clues on how to use it.
First I ran it without parameters and got this error:

```
Production-publish.ps1 : The term 'Production-publish.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Production-publish.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Production-publish.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Next I added the needed parameters:

```
.\Production-publish -packOutput 'C:\code\my-dotnetcore-proj\publish' -pubProfilePath 'Production.pubxml'
```

Which ran without error but didn't do ANYTHING!

How can I make the Azure depoyment via Powershell work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging through the `publish-module.psm1` to figure out why nothing was getting deployed I noticed that the command is required to supply more parameters. This is how:

```
.\Production-publish -packOutput 'C:\code\my-dotnetcore-proj\publish' -pubProfilePath 'Production.pubxml' -publishProperties @{
    'username' = '%PublishProfile.Username%'
    'Password' = '%PublishProfile.Password%'
    'AllowUntrustedCertificate' = false
    'AuthType' = 'Basic'}
```

You obviously have to replace `%PublishProfile.Username%` and `%PublishProfile.Password%` and possibly modify `Production-publish` and `Production.pubxml`

*Note that only the `Password` parameter is required (considering that the UserName is provided in your .pubxml file)*

I actually ended up writing blog article on how to compile and deploy asp.net core sites with TeamCity:
[How to deploy ASP.NET Core sites using Teamcity to Azure/IIS … or just command line](https://medium.com/monkii/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-sites-using-teamcity-or-just-command-line-cf05fdee58f5)